# Can one do a sumif(s) on a dynamic (spilled) range and return a (2d) array?

Tags: excel, sumifs, spill-range

Just curious if it's possible to get spill range output from a sum or sumif formula in excel.  Given a 2D array, I'd like to sum some rows but preserve the columns.  My concern is that once you add a sum or sumif to a spilling formula (sequence, filter, etc.), you lose the spill effect.  My interest in doing this is keeping tables automatically updated as the input table changes size.

A picture probably describes this the best: My table has rows with some repeated labels; I'd like to collapse those to a shorter table with unique row labels.  For example, B and D rows are repeated, these rows should be summed in the final output.  (The output in the example here is manually done, where I do a sumif in each row/column of the output.)

Thanks very much!

[image: sample image]

Comment: `SUMIFS` can spill: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qido6.png

Comment: @BigBen: great to know that sumifs can spill; I did not know that!  You answer gets me partly to my answer - this would take care of the case when the # of rows changes.  That's a big help.  But if the columns were to change, this would require dragging the formula across columns.  Are there any ways around that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `MAKEARRAY` and `LAMBDA` functions it is possible.

The formula is as follows:

```
=MAKEARRAY(
   ROWS(F3#),
   COLUMNS(G2#),
   LAMBDA(
      r,
      c,
      SUM(
          B3:D10 * 
          --(A3:A10=INDEX(F3#,r)) * 
          --(B2:D2=INDEX(G2#,1,c))
      )
   )
)
```

The `MAKEARRAY` formula spans an array with the required number of rows and columns via the first two parameters `ROWS(F3#)` and `COLUMNS(G2#)` (note that `F3# = F3:F8` and `G2# = G2:I2`).

The third parameter of `MAKEARRAY` takes the `LAMBDA` function and provides provides the number of rows `r` and columns `c` to its first two parameters.

The third parameter of `LAMBDA` takes here the `SUM` function to simulate a `SUMIFS` calculation. It has three factors:

1. The data range `B3:D10`
2. The row condition `--(A3:A10=INDEX(F3#,r))`
3. The column condition `--(B2:D2=INDEX(G2#,1,c))`
   The conditions in 2) and 3) result to 1 or 0 when applicable or not. So the `SUM` counts a value where it matches and 0 where it does not. Besides, the formulas in 2) and 3) are using row number `r` and column number `c` with `INDEX` to obtain the condition values.

[image: Using MAKEARRAY and LAMBDA creates the 2d spilling sumifs]

[image: The formula used to create the 2d spilling sumifs]